# C++ Esp32 functional infinite loop

Tags: c++, function, infinite-loop, esp32

So I've such of a code:

```
void B();
void C();

void A() {
  Serial.println("Looping");
  B();
}

void B() {
  C();
}

void C() {
  A();
}


void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  A();
}

void loop() {
 
};
```

and it works just fine, but when I want to add a condition, like this:

```
bool flag = false;

void B();
void C();

void A() {  
  Serial.println("Looping");
  if(flag)
    B();
  else 
    C();
}

void B() {
  flag = false;
  A();
}

void C() {
  flag = true;
  A();
}


void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  A();
}

void loop() {
 
};
```

After a while my esp32 throws a backtrace and reboots:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered
```

I need some kind of solution to run `B()` or `C()` and "forget" about `A()` body, as I understood this problem.

**UDP**
It's just a skelet of a real code, I'm using FreeRTOS (xTaskCreate, ...) to run the logic,
I`ve an idea:

```
1) Create 2 Tasks (one of them will be running) 
2) Later pass the function I want to call, delete running
3) Such way by switching tasks it should work
```

I've such logic in a project:

```
void B();
void C();

void A() {    
  if(server.connect())
    while(server.isConnected()) {
      //makeUpdate, receive new messages
    }

  //  as it fails, make reconnect
  //check wifi connection
    if(wifi)
      B();
    else 
      C();  
}

void B() {
  // Update Connection With Wifi
  // Go back to connect
  A();
}

void C() {
  // Update Connection With Gprs
  // Go back to connect
  A();
}


void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  A();
}

void loop() {
 
};
```

Comment: `A()` calls itself causing an infinite recursion, I think you don't want that

Comment: `A()` calls `B()` or `C()`, `B()` or `C()` calls `A()`. This will cause an infinite recursion which will exhaust the stack sooner or later. (It wouldn't do so with tail call optimization but I wouldn't count on it.) Why don't you wrap the calls of `B()` or `C()` just in a `for (;;)` loop if you intend to achieve infinite looping?

Comment: In real, I'm using this to switch state, when it changes. I don't need to call it so fast. Let's say function `A` is connector to server, `B` and `C` just possible way to connect `Wifi` & `Gprs`, when one of them fails I need to reconnect with another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling functions like that will cause an infinite recursion, exhaust the stack and make the whole thing crash.

You could call all the functions from inside `loop()` and other functions just return which function should be called next.

```cpp
char A() {
  Serial.println("Looping");
  if(flag)
    return 'B';
  else
    return 'C';
}

char B() {
  // Update Connection With Wifi
  // Go back to connect
  return 'A';
}

char C() {
  // Update Connection With Gprs
  // Go back to connect
  return 'A';
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  static char next_function = 'A';
  switch(next_function) {
    case 'A': next_function = A(); break;
    case 'B': next_function = B(); break;
    case 'C': next_function = C(); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: As I told, I'm using FreeRTOS, so it runs inside thread and  I've abot 15 function like `A()` `B()`,  `C()` that swithes current state, It's not just going from `B` or `C` to `A`

Comment: You could probably also make it return function pointers, which would avoid using a long switch statement.